# List obejct is not callable

Tags: python, telebot

как типичный новичок скопировал и вставил код, но тут ошибка :

```
     **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\telegaBot.py", line 7, in <module>
    @bot.message_handlers(commands=['start'])
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable**
```

Код

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой_токен')

@bot.message_handlers(commands=coms)
def start(message) :
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет !</b>', parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Извините за код без подсветки и отступов... пишу с телефона )

Comment: гугель вроде бы с телефона тоже работает, что помешало погуглить, что означает эта ошибка

Comment: да и не похоже, что ошибка отсюда. В коде нет такой строчки, которая указана в ошибке.

Comment: Лишняя буква `s` в конце: `@bot.message_handlers` -> `@bot.message_handler`

Answer (score 0):

Я увидел несколько ошибок, попробуйте исправить их, может заработает :)

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой_токен')

@bot.message_handlers(commands=['Команда1 без /', 'Команда2'])
def start(message) :
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Привет !</b>', parse_mode='html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```